# Not understanding some basic compilation errors in Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I've been studying Java for 2 months now and everytime I think I start to get a hang of it, I realize I still lack some strong fundamental.

Currently working on a exam-prep, and one of the exercise is to detect the compilation errors. While the answers are given, I still don't understand most of these errors.

Here is the code:

```
boolean b = true;
String s;
char c = '8';                    // unicode = 56
byte k = 6;
int i = 7;

b = !b < false;                  // compilation error #1
s = k + c + "" + (c < 8);
s = k + c + (c < 8) + "" ;       // compilation error #2
c = c + 1;                       // compilation error #3
b = b + "";                      // compilation error #4
c++;
b = true == (!(true != !(i != 7)) !=b || (c < '2'));
b = (true || false) == 1 && b;   // compilation error #5
```

**I understand error #1 and #5.**

**I don't understand error #2**. It seems to be a problem with the addition of a int and a boolean, but if this is the case, why isn't there a compilation error for the line before, which is exactly the same line of code minus the position of "" and (c < 8). I've seen compilation without errors before of booleanstring such as

```
(5 < 3) + "ok" = "falseok"
```

Does it means that the concatenation of boolean can only by done with Stringchain, but not other primitive? Then why does the second line compile?

**I don't understand error #3**. The compilator says : "incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char".. Why doesnt the char get implicitly converted to int? We learned in class that byte, short and char type could automatically get converted to int if in the same equation than and it, so why doesn't it happens here?

**I don't understand error #4**. The compilator says : "incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to boolean". Same as #1, why in this case a booleanString concatenation isn't accepted?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

- **#2** occures because `c<8` is evaluated to a `boolean` which can't be added to an `int`. There is no compilation error in the line
  before because the `boolean` expression is converted to a `String`
  before being concatenated. **Be aware that the order matters!** While `s = k + c + (c < 8) + ""` is not a valid expression, `s = "" + k + c + (c < 8)` is one.
- **#3** occures because the expression `c + 1` evaluates to an `int` whose storage size is greater than that of a `char`, so it has
  to be cast like so: `(char) (c + 1)`.
- **#4** occures because you can't assign a `String` expression to a `boolean` variable

Take a look at the specification of the [`+` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18) to understand what actually happens and to the [narrowing primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) section to see why the cast is needed.

And don't worry about not understanding everything from the beginning: We all started there. Java has gathered some peculiarities over the time. The best thing you can do (IMHO) is to learn to read the specification.